# Matlab: Angle between classifiers trained from fitcsvm

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I trained two svm models like the following

```
mdl_1{n} = fitcsvm(A,B);
mdl_2{n} = fitcsvm(C,D);
```

So for each trained svm model, there should be a classifier. If, I wanted to compute the angle between the classifiers of the two svm models, is the code below correct? Do I need to take the bias term in to account? Thanks a lot.

```
(subspace(mdl_1.Beta,mdl_2.Beta))*180/pi;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the bias term since the angle between (hyper)planes dont change with translation. That's reading the word "angle" verbatim. This isn't a programming question though.

Comment: So the code that i used to compute the angle between the classifiers is correct?

Comment: From the documentations: `.beta` is [an orthogonal vector to the hyperplane](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) (ctrl+f SVM binary classification algorithm) and in [`subspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subspace.html) "If A and B are column vectors of unit length, this is the same as acos(abs(A'*B))". Is there anything out of the two docs that you are not sure of?